# Disabling the previous date based on current date using angular material

Tags: angular-material

I found this snippet to disable the previous dates

```
<md-datepicker 
           ng-model="myDate" 
           md-placeholder="Enter date"
           md-min-date="minDate" 
           md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>
```

but instead of entering the minDate i want to assign the system date.
pls do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asign to minDate the value of today like this

```
var minDate = new Date();
```